# Assembly ADC (Add with carry) to C++

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, bigint, carryflag

There is an x86 assembly instruction `ADC`. I've found this means "Add with carry". What does this mean/do? How would one implement the behavior of this instruction in C++?

**INFO:**
Compiled on Windows. I'm using a 32-bit Windows Installation. My processor is Core 2 Duo from Intel.

Comment: @Chubsdad: I've done my best to add some information. I hope it is enough.

Comment: Which compiler? To access the carry flag, you have to embed assembler code in your C++ code. How you do this depends on the compiler that you are using.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

ADC is the same as ADD but adds an extra 1 if processor's carry flag is set.

Comment: Alright! Thank you. But now, I have to know IF the flag is set. Is this possible in C++?

Comment: Not with standard C++, you have to use an "asm" code block. I don't remember the exact syntax, but you'll lose code portability.

Comment: The idea of ADC is not to know the carry flag, but to do an ADD before ADC, so the carry will be set when the ADD overflows

Comment: @Martijn, if you want to know the carry flag status you may do something like this:

pushfd;
pop eax;
now carry flag is at bit 0 of eax.

Comment: Downvoted for not really answering the C++ aspect of the question.  Also, that asm sequence kinda sucks compare to `setc al`  (and `movzx eax, al` if desired).  `pushf` is a 3-uop instruction on Intel SnB-family CPUs.  The push/pop store-forwarding round-trip adds ~5 cycles of latency to the dependency chain involving CF.

Answer (score 10):

The C++ language doesn't have any concept of a carry flag, so making an intrinsic function wrapper around the [`ADC` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ADC.html) is clunky.  However, Intel did it anyway:  [`unsigned char _addcarry_u32 (unsigned char c_in, unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned * out);`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=addcarry&expand=3021,3513,3519,3574,3575,139,138). Last I checked, gcc did a poor job with this (saving the carry result into an integer register, instead of leaving it in CF), but hopefully Intel's own compiler does better.

See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for assembly documentation.

---

The compiler will use ADC for you when adding integers wider than a single register, e.g. adding `int64_t` in 32bit code, or `__int128_t` in 64bit code.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#ifdef __x86_64__
__int128_t add128(__int128_t a, __int128_t b) { return a+b; }
#endif
    # clang 3.8 -O3  for x86-64, SystemV ABI.
    # __int128_t args passed in 2 regs each, and returned in rdx:rax
    add     rdi, rdx
    adc     rsi, rcx
    mov     rax, rdi
    mov     rdx, rsi
    ret
```

asm output from the [Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-Wall+-Wextra+-fverbose-asm+-O3',source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0A//+uses+adc+with+-m32%0Aint64_t+add64(int64_t+a,+int64_t+b)+%7B+return+a%2Bb%3B+%7D%0A%0A%23ifdef+__x86_64__%0A__int128_t+add128(__int128_t+a,+__int128_t+b)+%7B+return+a%2Bb%3B+%7D%0A%23endif%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3).  clang's `-fverbose-asm` isn't very vebose, but gcc 5.3 / 6.1 wastes two `mov` instructions so it's less readable.

You can sometimes hand-hold compilers into emitting an `adc` or otherwise using the carry-out of `add` using the idiom `uint64_t sum = a+b;` / `carry = sum < a;`.  But extending this to get a carry-out from an `adc` instead of `add` is not possible with current compilers; `c+d+carry_in` can wrap all the way around, and compilers don't manage to optimize the multiple checks for carry out on each `+` in `c+d+carry` if you do it safely.

---

### Clang `_ExtInt`

There is one way I'm aware of to get a chain of add/adc/.../adc: Clang's new `_ExtInt(width)` feature that provides fixed-bit-width types of any size up to 16,777,215 bits ([blog post](http://The%20New%20Clang%20_ExtInt%20Feature%20Provides%20Exact%20Bitwidth%20Integer%20Types)).  It was added to clang's development version on April 21, 2020, so it's not yet in any released version.

This will hopefully show up in ISO C and/or C++ at some point; The [N2472](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2472.pdf) proposal is apparently being "being actively considered by the ISO WG14 C Language Committee"

```
typedef _ExtInt(256) wide_int;

wide_int add ( wide_int a, wide_int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

compiles as follows with clang trunk `-O2` for x86-64 ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'typedef+_ExtInt(256)+wide_int%3B%0A%0Awide_int+add+(+wide_int+a,+wide_int+b)+%7B%0A++++return+a%2Bb%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A/*%0A%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%0A//+from+the+blog+post,+doesn!'t+compile.%0Atemplate%3Csize_t+WidthA,+size_t+WidthB%3E%0A++_ExtInt(WidthA+%2B+WidthB)+lossless_mul(_ExtInt(WidthA)+a,+_ExtInt(WidthB)+b)+%7B%0A++return+static_cast%3C_ExtInt(WidthA+%2B+WidthB)%3E(a)+%0A+++++++*+static_cast%3C_ExtInt(WidthA+%2B+WidthB)%3E(b)%3B%0A%7D+%0A*/%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),header:(),k:51.2402088772846,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:48.7597911227154,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)):

```
add(int _ExtInt<256>, int _ExtInt<256>):
        add     rsi, r9
        adc     rdx, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        adc     rcx, qword ptr [rsp + 16]
        mov     rax, rdi                        # return the retval pointer
        adc     r8, qword ptr [rsp + 24]        # chain of ADD / 3x ADC!

        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 8], rdx        # store results to mem
        mov     qword ptr [rdi], rsi
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 16], rcx
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 24], r8
        ret
```

Apparently `_ExtInt` is passed by value in integer registers until the calling convention runs out of registers.  (At least in this early version;  Perhaps x86-64 SysV should class it as "memory" when it's wider than 2 or maybe 3 registers, like structs larger than 16 bytes.  Although moreso than structs, having it in registers is likely to be useful.  Just put other args first so they're not displaced.)

The first _ExtInt arg is in R8:RCX:RDX:RSI, and the second has its low qword in R9, with the rest in memory.

A pointer to the return-value object is passed as a hidden first arg in RDI; x86-64 System V only ever returns in up to 2 integer registers (RDX:RAX) and this doesn't change that.

Comment: It's *almost* 4 years now, I still can't make the compilers (gcc, clang) work to generate `add`, `adc` instruction chain. Do you think it's possible now?

Comment: @madhur4127: For just two instructions, yes that's possible from pure C with the `sum=a+b;` / `carry = sum<a;` trick, or `__int128`.  But for longer chains compilers are still terrible AFAIK, even with `_addcarry_u32`.

Comment: @madhur4127: update: clang `_ExtInt` can let you use a fixed-width integer type of any width up to 16,777,215 bits.  (http://blog.llvm.org/2020/04/the-new-clang-extint-feature-provides.html).  https://godbolt.org/z/bsDCvh shows that `+` on `_ExtInt(256)` compiles to `add` / `adc` / `adc` / `adc`.

Comment: The current version of ExtInt just unrolls everything, I see 4000+ lines of assembly with 2048*2048 multiplication without any loops. At (1<<20) bits, compiler explorer killed the process because of timeout.

Comment: @madhur4127: lol, that's amusing, thanks for checking on that.  So not currently practical for very large integers, especially for multiply.

Answer (score 9):

From [here](http://mtciswat.com/totorials/assembly/x86asm/asml1003.html) (broken) or [here](http://www.oocities.org/siliconvalley/park/3230/x86asm/asml1003.html)

> However, Intel processor
>   has a special instruction called adc.
>   This command behaves similarly as the
>   add command. The only extra thing is
>   that it also add the value carry flag
>   along. So, this may be very handy to
>   add large integers. Suppose you'd like
>   to add a 32-bit integers with 16-bit
>   registers. How can we do that? Well,
>   let's say that the first integer is
>   held on the register pair DX:AX, and
>   the second one is on BX:CX. This is
>   how:
>
> ```
> add  ax, cx
> adc  dx, bx
> ```
>
> Ah, so first, the lower 16-bit is added by
>   add ax, cx. Then the higher 16-bit is
>   added using adc instead of add. It is
>   because: if there are overflows, the
>   carry bit is automatically added in
>   the higher 16-bit. So, no cumbersome
>   checking. This method can be extended
>   to 64 bits and so on... Note that: If
>   the 32-bit integer addition overflows
>   too at the higher 16-bit, the result
>   will not be correct and the carry flag
>   is set, e.g. Adding 5 billion to 5
>   billion.

Everything from here on, remember that it falls pretty much into the zone of implementation defined behavior.

Here's a small sample that works for VS 2010 (32-bit, WinXp)

Caveat: $7.4/1- "The asm declaration is conditionally-supported; its meaning is implementation-defined. [ Note: Typically it is used to pass information through the implementation to an assembler. —end note ]"

```
int main(){
   bool carry = false;
   int x = 0xffffffff + 0xffffffff;
   __asm {
      jc setcarry
setcarry:
      mov carry, 1
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't block quote the 'Caveat....' portion in my response. Sometimes this formating just doesn't behave right.

Comment: 0xffffffff is either -1 or UINT_MAX, which is being stored in an int. Perhaps 'x' should be an unsigned int, or the summands should be INT_MAX (0x7fffffff). If we take the summands to be the same type as the result (ie, signed integer), then OVERFLOW flag is not set - the result is -2 (0xfffffffe).

Comment: That code is ridiculous; **you can't depend on `CF` being set or not from a C statement outside the `asm` block**.  It might happen to work in debug mode, but that's not going to be useful with optimization enabled.  Also, use `setc carry` to set carry to 0 or 1, according to `CF`.

Answer (score 9):

The ADC behaviour can be simulated in both C and C++.  The following example adds two numbers (stored as arrays of unsigned as they are too large to fit into a single unsigned).

```
unsigned first[10];
unsigned second[10];
unsigned result[11];

....   /* first and second get defined */

unsigned carry = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    result[i] = first[i] + second[i] + carry;
    carry = (first[i] > result[i]);
}
result[10] = carry;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code will fail to set the carry if `second==~0U && carry==1`. e.g.: with 32bits unsigned that would be `second[i]==0xFFFFFFFF && carry==1`. In this case `first[i] == result[i]` even though an overflow (carry) has happened.

Comment: Working code is `unsigned tmp = second[i] + carry; result[i] = first[i] + tmp; carry = (first[i] > result[i]) | (second[i] > tmp);`

Comment: And the fact this is maddenly slow is why it's written in assembly right now.

Answer (score 5):

In x86-64, the **ADD** instruction adds two 64-bit integers: `add rax, rbx` does `rax = rax + rbx`.
It also sets the carry flag to 1 when there was unsigned overflow (= when the result didn't fit in 64 bits), otherwise it sets the carry flag to 0.

In C++, you can simulate ADD like this:

```
uint64_t a, b;
bool carry;

a += b;
carry = (a < b);  // a+b can't be smaller than b: there must have been an overflow
```

The **ADC** instruction is like ADD, but adds the carry flag to the result:
`adc rax, rbx` does `rax = rax + rbx + carry_flag`.
It also sets the carry flag if there was unsigned overflow.

In C++:

```
uint64_t tmp = b + carry;
a += tmp;
carry = (tmp < carry) + (a < tmp);  // only one overflow can happen
```

The ADD and ADC instructions can be used to add big integers (with *n* "digits").
Use ADD for the least significant digits, then use ADC (*n* – 1) times to add the rest of the digits.
This is the “**schoolbook addition algorithm**”.

For example, adding 256-bit big integers with four 64-bit "digits":

```
mov rax, [rsi]        ; load the least significant source digit
mov rbx, [rsi + 8]    ; ...
mov rcx, [rsi + 16]
mov rdx, [rsi + 24]
add [rdi], rax        ; add it to the least significant destination digit
adc [rdi + 8], rbx    ; ... propagate carry up
adc [rdi + 16], rcx
adc [rdi + 24], rdx
```

Recent versions of the `clang` compiler can recognize big integer addition and [use ADD/ADC to implement it](https://godbolt.org/z/vb9G7ocsY).

```
constexpr uint64_t n = 4;
uint64_t dst[n], src[n];

// Add src to dst.
uint64_t carry = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  uint64_t tmp = src[i] + carry;
  dst[i] += tmp;
  carry = (tmp < carry) + (dst[i] < tmp);
}
```

Comment: Very cool, finally a way to write this in pure ISO C++ that compiles to a chain of `adc` instructions with both carry-in and carry-out (with Clang 9 and later; clang 8 and earlier miss the peephole optimization and materialize `carry` as a 0/1 with `setc` aka `setb`.)

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in this.  Try this input:

```
unsigned first[10] =  {0x00000001};
unsigned second[10] = {0xffffffff, 0xffffffff};
```

The result should be {0, 0, 1, ...} but the result is {0, 0, 0, ...}

Changing this line:

```
carry = (first[i] > result[i]);
```

to this:

```
if (carry)
    carry = (first[i] >= result[i]);
else
    carry = (first[i] > result[i]);
```

fixes it.

Comment: `carry=(carry&&first[i]>=result[i])||(!carry&&first[i]>result[i])` avoids branching and does the same thing, if anyone is interested.

Comment: Actually `||` and `&&` causes branching since they only evaluate the right side as necessary. There are more branching in the one-liner than with the easy-to-read if() statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is my fastest Code:

```
template <class Ty>
constexpr bool add_carry_ux(bool carry_in, Ty src1, Ty src2, Ty* sum_out)
{
    const Ty sum = src1 + src2;
    const bool carry_out = (sum < src1) | ((sum == ~static_cast<Ty>(0)) & carry_in);

    *sum_out = sum + carry_in;

    return carry_out;
}
```

**ASM:**

```
add_carry_ux(bool, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long*):
        add     rsi, rdx
        movzx   eax, dil
        setc    dl
        add     rax, rsi
        cmp     rsi, -1
        mov     QWORD PTR [rcx], rax
        sete    al
        movzx   edx, dl
        and     eax, edi
        or      eax, edx
        ret
```

Comment: [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153852/assembly-adc-add-with-carry-to-c/75759422#75759422) on this question shows code that can compile to a single `adc` with recent clang.  Does this do any better when it inlines so the carry_in and carry_out can be in CF?  Because this looks like a lot of asm.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
int32_t adc(uint32_t first, uint32_t second, uint32_t *carry)
    {
        uint32_t res;
        uint32_t carry_out = 0;
    
        if (!*carry)
        {
            res = first + second;
            *carry = (res < first) && (res < second);
    
            return res;
        }
    
        res = adc(first, second, &carry_out);
        if (*carry)
        {
            res++;
            carry_out |= !res;
        }
        
        *carry = carry_out;
    
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Building a 16-bit add-with-carry out of wider operations kind of defeats the purpose.  Just right-shift `result >> 16` to get the high half (carry out), or just *use* that wider type directly and let the compiler implement it with `adc` or whatever is efficient on the target ISA.

Comment: Also, if `unsigned int` actually is a 16-bit type like you seem to be assuming, `first + second` already wraps before you assign to `result`.  Perhaps you meant `first + (unsigned long)second`?

Comment: You can [edit] your answer to replace bad code with good code.  But note that the hard part of implementing ADC in pure C is handling carry-in.  Your `result < second` is sufficient to detect carry-out, but you shouldn't add it to *this* element, you should return it separately. That's like `add eax, ecx` / `adc eax, 0` which is almost never what you want.

Comment: I think this new version fails for cases like `0xffffffff + 0 + carry=1`.  The while loop does `0xffffffff + 1 = 0`, producing a carry-out, which makes the while loop run again producing res=1 and carry=0.  Then it tailcalls itself to do `1 + 0`, returning 1 and leaving carry=0, when the correct result is `0` with carry=1.  Carry-out in either `+` operation in `first + second + *carry` needs to send a carry-out to the final `*carry` output, *not* add back into the return value.  Remember, carry-out is bit 33 of a 32+32 => 33-bit addition, but carry-in has a place value of just 1.