# How is the carry flag being set in this assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly, random, carryflag, 65816

Given the following assembly code for a 16-bit PRNG function,

```
$80/8111 E2 20       SEP #$20   ; set 8-bit mode accumulator
$80/8113 AD E5 05    LDA $05E5  ; load low byte of last random number
$80/8116 8D 02 42    STA $4202
$80/8119 A9 05       LDA #$05   ; multiply it by 5
$80/811B 8D 03 42    STA $4203
$80/811E EA          NOP
$80/811F C2 20       REP #$20   ; set 16-bit mode accumulator
$80/8121 AD 16 42    LDA $4216  ; load the resultant product
$80/8124 48          PHA        ; push it onto the stack
$80/8125 E2 20       SEP #$20   ; 8-bit
$80/8127 AD E6 05    LDA $05E6  ; load high byte of last random number
$80/812A 8D 02 42    STA $4202
$80/812D A9 05       LDA #$05   ; multiply by 5
$80/812F 8D 03 42    STA $4203
$80/8132 EB          XBA        ; exchange high and low bytes of accumulator
$80/8133 EA          NOP
$80/8134 AD 16 42    LDA $4216  ; load low byte of product
$80/8137 38          SEC
$80/8138 63 02       ADC $02,s  ; add to it the high byte of the original product
$80/813A 83 02       STA $02,s  ; save it to the high byte of the original product
$80/813C C2 20       REP #$20   ; 16-bit
$80/813E 68          PLA        ; pull it from the stack
$80/813F 69 11 00    ADC #$0011 ; add 11
$80/8142 8D E5 05    STA $05E5  ; save as new random number
$80/8145 6B          RTL
```

a user by the name of @sagara translated the code to C:

```c
#define LOW(exp)  ((exp) & 0x00FF)
#define HIGH(exp) (((exp) & 0xFF00) >> 8)

uint16_t prng(uint16_t v) {

    uint16_t low  = LOW(v);
    uint16_t high = HIGH(v);

    uint16_t mul_low  = low  * 5;
    uint16_t mul_high = high * 5;

    // need to check for overflow, since final addition is adc as well
    uint16_t v1    = LOW(mul_high) + HIGH(mul_low) + 1;
    uint8_t  carry = HIGH(v1) ? 1 : 0;

    uint16_t v2 = (LOW(v1) << 8) + LOW(mul_low);

    return (v2 + 0x11 + carry);
}
```

I'm confused by two things.

1. In this line...

   ```
   uint16_t v1    = LOW(mul_high) + HIGH(mul_low) + 1;
   ```

   **Why is there a `+ 1`? I think it's because of the `ADC` operation, but how can we be sure that the carry flag is set to 1?** What previous operation would guarantee this? The `XBC`? I read a few posts such as [Assembly ADC (Add with carry) to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153852/assembly-adc-add-with-carry-to-c) and [Overflow and Carry flags on Z80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034566/overflow-and-carry-flags-on-z80) but it's not clear to me because <strike>the instruction set appears to be different</strike> I'm not familiar with [65C816 assembly](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Super_NES_Programming/65c816_reference#Addressing_modes). (This is from a popular 1994 SNES game whose NA release anniversary recently passed; free upvote to the correct guess :-)
2. In the next line...

   ```
   uint8_t  carry = HIGH(v1) ? 1 : 0;
   ```

   **Why would it work this way? I read this as, *"Set the carry flag if and only if the high byte is non-zero."* But wouldn't the indication of an overflow be only if the high byte *is* zero?** (I'm probably misinterpreting what the line is doing.)

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: What assembly language is this? The posts you linked are for different instruction sets. Please tag this appropriately.

Comment: @interjay - As mentioned in my post, it's from a game cartridge from 1994, but I have no idea what language—I was hoping someone could identify it, because today is literally my first day looking at assembly. I've already tried Googling extensively, _e.g._ "<game> assembly instruction set".

Comment: Looks like 6502 assembly, or some sort of modification of it.

Comment: It just hit me that the instruction set is obviously related to the CPU, not the game cartridge. I found [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Super_NES_Programming/Introduction_to_assembly) that it might be the "65816." Ah, [here's the full instruction set](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Super_NES_Programming/65c816_reference#Addressing_modes).

Comment: Now I know what that looked familiar. Has been a while since I've worked with NES assembly.

Comment: Yep, that's 65C816 assembly, which is the CPU that the SNES's 5A22 was based on.

Comment: All the Motorola assemblers look pretty much like this.

Comment: The line `$80/8137 38 SEC` is explicity setting the carry just before an `ADC` add-with-carry instruction, that's why the `+1` in the C code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. but how can we be sure that the carry flag is set to 1? What previous operation would guarantee this?

```
$80/8137 38          SEC   ; SEt Carry flag
```

---

> 2. `uint8_t  carry = HIGH(v1) ? 1 : 0;`
>      Why would it work this way? I read this as, "Set the carry flag if and only if the high byte is non-zero." But wouldn't the indication of an overflow be only if the high byte is zero?

The addition `ADC #$0011` is using the carry from `ADC $02,s`. When `ADC $02,s` is performed, the accumulator is set to 8-bit (because of `SEP #$20`), so the carry flag will be set if the result of `ADC $02,s` would've exceeded 8 bits (i.e. if you would've got something >= $100 in 16-bit mode).
In the C version you've got a 16-bit variable (`v1`) to hold the result, so your carry will be in bit 8 of `v1`, which you can test with `HIGH(v1) == 1`, or simply `HIGH(v1)` since it will either be 1 or 0.

Comment: Ah, I've realized why (2) was throwing me off. I mistakenly read the `LOW(mul_high) + HIGH(mul_low)` as concatenating two 8-bit strings (as if one of them were shifted) instead of simply being added. So I was under the impression that the `HIGH(v1)` could be any range of numbers, hence my whole "non-zero" thing. But your explanation cleared it up: only 1 bit can be set in this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew Cheong it was done that way because C does not have a "carry".

Answer (score 3):

1) The line

```
$80/8137 38     SEC
```

is explicity setting the carry just before an `ADC` add-with-carry instruction, that's why the `+1` in the C code.

2) The processor has an 8-bit accumulator, and the addition will overflow to the carry, ready for the next `ADC` instruction. However, the C code is using a 16-bit variable `v1`, and the carry remains in the upper 8 bits. Hence the test of those upper 8 bits to extract the so-called "carry".